# Why was S03E21 of Star Trek: Enterprise named "E²"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

The name of [Season 03 Episode 21 of Star Trek: Enterprise](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/E%C2%B2_(episode)) was E². Why?

All episodes had a meaningful name which was related with the story, but I am unable to understand why that episode was named E². Is it just a meaningless fancy name for an episode with temporal ju-ju? Or, is there something from physics which fits in the equation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The episode deals with the *Enterprise* encountering a second, alternate version of their ship.

The alternate version of the ship came into being after entering an unstable subspace corridor and going back in time 117 years.

Since there were two *Enterprise* ships, E<sup>2</sup> refers to this (*Enterprise* *  *Enterprise* = *Enterprise*<sup>2</sup>, or E<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Wow... nice one. But, is it just your fabrication or it has official source?

Comment: I hope you meant "speculation", since "fabrication" implies dishonesty... but yes, this is speculation (although it seems pretty obvious given the context, and more plausible than just some random characters strung together that are unrelated to the plot).

Comment: @SachinShekhar I seriously doubt there is an "official source" for why most episodes are named what they are.

Comment: Since when do you multiply ship name together?

Comment: @user973810 There were two enterprise ships by eachother. E by E is E^2. It's like the old joke that Noah put animals on the ark 4 at a time because two by two they went on.

Comment: @user973810 Since when do you have to have a logical precedent to come up with an episode name?

Comment: @user973810 Because 2E - "too-ee" - sounds silly?  But if we want to extend the multiplication part further, the crew of the second Enterprise did multiply - by having descendents.

Comment: @Izkata If they were trying not to be silly, explain why they ever made this terrible series.

Comment: @user973810 It was made because it was a good concept.  It's also the entire reason I got into Star Trek, and I'm now one of the top Trek users on this site - and personally, I place ENT tied with TNG for quality.